# ms access display inputs of textbox1 in textbox2 in realtime

Tags: ms-access, vba

i'm working on some VBA code for msaccess, basically i want to display the data i typed on textbox1 to textbox2. i have tried all the events available and it ain't work.

i have tried this

```
Private Sub input1_AfterUpdate()
output1.Value = input1.Value
End Sub
```

on key down and after update. it works on after update but i need to refresh the page before the inputs are loaded to textbox2.

what i need is realtime update, everytime i typed something on textbox1, it will display on textbox2, including the previous letters i typed.

thanks a lot guys, badly need a solution for this :(

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `Change` event and `Text` property:

```
Private Sub textbox1_Change()
     textbox2.Value = textbox1.Text
End Sub
```

We take `.Text` property of source textbox, because `.Value` is changed after the end of edition.

Comment: i have used that too and its not working also ...it only works when you confirm the textbox was changed ... u can see result once you complete typing the entire words , i need to see every input is reflected

Comment: @jake did you use `Text` property?

Comment: i tried on change and action messagebox, it worked everytime i typed the box appeared but using vba, its not working

Comment: basically using set value on macro or the vba code above functions like after update event where in fact it is on change ..

Comment: @jake i mean read `Text`, not `Value` of changing textbox. Please, show you code of your attempt.

Comment: `Private Sub input1_Change()
Me!output1 = Me!input1
End Sub`

Comment: also tried this: `Private Sub input1_Change()
output1.Value = input1.Value
End Sub
`

Comment: PLease, look at my code and realize, `.Text` NOT `.Value` at right of `=`